# Mathematical Knowledge for Teaching

Tags: undergraduate-education, course-design, primary-education, graduate-education

Does anyone know of any course called Mathematical Knowledge for Teaching?  Where is this course taught?  If it's not a course, is there any workshop about this?  Or possible a book? It's not knowing how to do math but how to teach math (focus on conceptual understanding and problem solving rather than merely procedural skills) especially in elementary/middle school.

Answer (score 12):

(Perhaps this should be a comment, but it's pretty much an answer.)

Mathematical Knowledge for Teaching (MKT) is based on the more general term Pedagogical Content Knowledge (PCK) due to Lee Shulman. For MKT, see the work of DL Ball. **[Link](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=deborah%20ball%20%22mathematical%20knowledge%20for%20teaching%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22)**.

Deborah Ball is currently at the University of Michigan; you can find courses and related research projects on MKT there. For example, see [**this section**](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~dball/projects/index.html) of her site.

Here is an image to help summarize the MKT model (see [**here**](http://www.uni.edu/ctlm/content/mathematical-knowledge-teaching) for more):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin, for the comprehensive answer to my question.  I checked out the websites and the links.  Just like the Stanford online course that JPBurke recommended, I look forward to learning more about MKT from all the information you shared.

Comment: [Only as this MKT thread was bumped over a year later have I realized that, in the summary image, there is an egregious typo: **knowledge** is misspelled!]

Answer (score 7):

Benjamin gave the appropriate answer about what is MKT (and the famous diagram known to my friends as "the egg").

I'm hoping to address the part of your question in which you are looking for a course that might help you explore the idea of "how to teach math (focus on conceptual understanding and problem solving rather than merely procedural skills)." This sort of view of math falls very much within Jo Boaler's research. And you're lucky, because she has a [free online course How To Learn Math](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Education/EDUC115N/How_to_Learn_Math/about) running in a couple of weeks, open for registration now.

The summer version of the course is for educators, and the school year version is for anyone wanting to learn more about their own math learning.

To be clear, this is not a course about MKT. It's a course that addresses math *teaching and learning* from someone who values a problem solving approach.

[Here's a video with Prof. Boaler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ien-86bXCrI) talking a little bit about her approach.

Comment: Thank you, JPBurke, for answering my question.  I registered online for the Stanford course.  I'm looking forward to learning from that course.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematics for secondary School Teachers*, put out by MAA, is a good text used at our universities here.  Also, [Hung-Hsi Wu](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wu/) at Berkeley has some good stuff for the elementary level.

Currently the [Mathematics Teacher Education Partnership](http://www.aplu.org/projects-and-initiatives/stem-education/mathematics-teacher-education-partnership/) has a team that is currently working to develop materials that are more aligned to teaching pre-service teachers that special MKT.